# yum.conf and installonlypkgs option

Tags: centos, rhel, yum, rpm

We set up our CentOS 6.x system that we could have a different versions of our software by means of `installonlypkgs` option in `yum.conf`. For example `<mycoolpackage>-1.0.0-0.el6` and `<mycoolpackage>-1.1.0-0.el6` can live together because they use version specific directories `1.0.0` and `1.1.0` respectively.

Now the problem arises when I'd like to do `yum update` and have packages like `<mycoolpackage>-1.1.0-0.rc28.el6` and `<mycoolpackage>-1.1.0-0.rc88.el6` for example. Since major version of the component is the same, of course there will be conflicting files.

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file <path> from install of <mycoolpackage>-1.1.0-0.rc88.el6 conflicts with file from package <mycoolpackage>-1.1.0-0.rc28.el6
```

The question is how to solve it by means of `yum` ideally? In other words I'd like `yum` to keep different software version as `installonlypkgs` option in `yum.conf` dictates, but *only* up to version. If *version* is the same but *release* is newer the package needs to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, this is solved with different package naming.
The first package would be mycoolpackage and the second one would be for example mycoolpackage1.

With this method you can have different versions of the same software installed and still update both versions via yum.

One example for this are the packages samba (samba version 3.6.9) and samba4 (samba version 4.0.0).

Comment: Yeah, thanks. From a user perspective I don't find this naming method useful. `yum` updates packages well enough with `installonlypkgs` option in `yum.conf`. The only issue I have at the moment is update of release candidates.